# When an object is moving, does air resistance build up after it begins to move or during?

Tags: friction, drag

For example,if a car is accelerating to 70km/h, when the car is at 35km/h, will air resistance also be at 35km/h or will it slowly build up after it begins accelerating?

Answer (score 0):

For macroscopic objects, the air resistance is:

$$F_{air} = Kv^2$$

where $K$ is a constant relating to the object's shape and orientation and the density of the fluid. The air resistance therefore depends only on the object's speed.